# how to deploy app project of react-native-web onto server end?

Tags: react-native

I am pretty new to react-native-web,

I just follow [enter link description here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/) and successfully build a dev version of web app

[image]

but I am not sure how to deploy these code onto my server, since I am using the share hosting server service, so I can't install components for my project, is there any way to build the bundle.js locally and I can just upload the js files to server end?

can anyone help me out?

asked @ github :[enter link description here](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/277)

Answer (score 0):

How to deploy? In the same way but into the server.
I mean, copy your project into the server, execute in the console **./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline** and now you can view the app running into ther server at http://localhost:8080/.

You have to replace "localhost" with "nameOfYourServer" to access from outside.

Of course you have to install everything (npm install) as you have installed locally.

Comment: I am using the share hosting server service, so I can't install components for my project,
is there any way to build the bundle.js locally and I can just upload the js files to server end?

Comment: Copying the project on a server and running './node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline' will result in a very readable live.bundle.js. Not very desirable.

Comment: To change the port which is specified in the environmental var PORT (like on Heroku) use:
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline **--port $PORT**